# Why am I getting linker errors for ws2_32.dll in my C program?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi, linker-errors, winsock2

I am writing my program in Visual Studio 2010.
I am unable to link a file named `ws2_32.dll` with my project.

Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you changed things in your project? What actual results were obtained? If there were error messages, what were they?

Answer (score 7):

Typically you dont link to ws2_32.dll **directly** but to WS2_32.Lib, which you can find in the Windows SDK. So in your code you write

```
#include <winsock2.h>
```

and to your linker-settings you add WS2_32.Lib and you're good to go.

The Windows SDK is here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx

Comment: If you've installed Visual Studio 2010 properly, you shouldn't need to download the SDK.

Comment: Or maybe it depeneds on the version; i dont know if that's still true for 2010, but in 2008 express it was not included. Thanks for the comment tho, hopefully it makes original poster look in the VS2010 default lib-folder first.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm not really sure about the Express edition. I've never used it. The full versions of both 2008 and 2010 include the Windows SDK, no extra downloads required. Including the link is still helpful, but I'd leave it as a last resort.

Comment: @eznme - Why?  The answer isn't the best answer.  You were not even aware of the limits of Visual Studio Express. Cody Gray's answer is much better.

Answer (score 6):

The first order of business is importing the header file that defines functions exported by `ws2_32.dll`. You do that by adding the following statement to the top of any source file that you wish to call those functions in:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
```

Then, you have to tell the linker where it can find the import library for that DLL. There are two ways to do that in Visual Studio, but the simplest way is adding the following line to your source code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

You could also add it as a dependency to your linker's "Additional Dependencies" property (find that under your Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input).

MSDN also has a [getting started guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545.aspx) that walks you through [creating a basic Winsock application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737629.aspx). Make sure that you've read it before proceeding any further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the file using [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you do not have the lib file.