# Deprecated commands in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, deprecated

When building a solution in Visual Studio 2013 of a project, I noticed that I am getting warnings for the following references:

> warning C4996: 'gethostbyname': Use getaddrinfo() or GetAddrInfoW() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings  src\core\JCSocket.cpp   77  1
>   warning C4996: 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings  src\core\JCSocket.cpp   82  1
>   warning C4996: 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings  src\core\JCSocket.cpp   121 1
>   warning C4996: 'inet_ntoa': Use inet_ntop() or InetNtop() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings  src\core\MuninNodeServer.cpp    64  1
>   warning C4996: 'GetVersionExW': was declared deprecated src\plugins\disk\DiskTimeMuninNodePlugin.cpp    48  1
>   warning C4996: 'GetVersion': was declared deprecated    src\plugins\external\ConsolePipe.cpp    12  1
>   warning C4996: 'GetVersionExW': was declared deprecated src\plugins\PerfCounterMuninNodePlugin.cpp  56  1
>   warning C4996: 'GetVersionExW': was declared deprecated src\plugins\uptime\UptimeMuninNodePlugin.cpp    34  1

Whenever I try to change it to the recommended IntelliSense command, it is saying:

> IntelliSense: identifier "inet_ntop" is undefined \src\core\MuninNodeServer.cpp   64  31

Comment: More info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234348/winsock-deprecated-no-warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors are telling you what to do. Microsoft is nice like that.

> `gethostbyname` -> [`getaddrinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   `inet_addr` -> [`inet_pton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   `inet_ntoa` -> [`inet_ntop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805843(v=vs.85).aspx)

As far as `GetVersionExW` and `GetVersion` Microsoft recommends using the appropriate [Version Helper Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I am still getting an error that the new replaced command is undefined when I change for instance inet_ntoa -> inet_ntop. Where shall I define it?

Comment: @Dean Meaning you're still getting the same errors? If so use Ctrl + Shift + F and search all your source files in the solution for `gethostname`, `inet_addr`, `inet_ntoa`, `GetVersionExW` and `GetVersion`. Also make sure you rebuilt your code, Ctrl + F7.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, tried replacing only one and still getting
Error 1 error C3861: 'inet_ntop': identifier not found \src\core\MuninNodeServer.cpp

Comment: @Dean Check out the links I provided when replacing each function. For `inet_ntop` you need to include Ws2tcpip.h and link in the Ws2_32.lib/dll.

Comment: Great, I managed the links, however the arguments are options, will need to research further. How and where in the VS Project do I link the DLL lib?

Comment: @Dean This question probably has the answers that you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5220309/2642059

Comment: For ``GetVersion`` and ``GetVersionEx``, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303824/warning-c4996-getversionexw-was-declared-deprecated) stackoverflow thread.

Comment: @thnee Well that was an embarrassing typo. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio tells you this warning cause you trying to use **unsecure function** which means includes the body of the function

and the body can obviously contain a signed overflow and there's a prospect to get another compiling errors or perhaps its not supported in the newer library

by the way, its about how you use this function

---

Simply you can disable the warning by add the following line

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4996)
```

at the **top** of your code

Which disable **warning** error code **4996** and will work fine without any problems.

> Another way:

1. from the **Solution Explorer** right click on the project and choose **Properties**
2. navigate to **Configuration Properties** >> **C/C++** >> **Advanced**
3. at the end just put **4996** in **disable specific warning** and click **Apply** >> **Ok**

> Note: I prefer ***code way*** at all, It's more good to learn if you're not
>   programming in visual studio or making a header file for
>   your library

Comment: I think your answer is incomplete, you just give a solution to ignore warnings (I know question is not clear). The problem could be elsewhere: for example using a newer version of the lib (he said he followed recommandations but it didn't work). But this is my opinion. Please edit your answer to remove some of your **bold** words, that'll make it easier to read/understand.

Comment: Sorry for that..I edited the answer to be more clear