# Error C4996 C++ Client & Server

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

So I am trying to build up a Server-Client program in C++. I am trying to make a more "Friendly" "Connect" function. But, I am having a problem. I am getting this error when I am running it.

> Error 1   error C4996: 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings

This is the `Connect()` function that it returns the error on:

```
bool Connect(std::string ip, TPort port) {
    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
    clientService.sin_port = htons(port);
    SOCKET connecter = connect(handle, 
                               (SOCKADDR *)& clientService,
                               sizeof(clientService));
    return (connecter == 0);
}
```

I searched a bit in the internet and didn't find something that helps me. The error comes from the line:

```
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
```

I am using windows API , and Visual Studio 2013

Comment: The error message is offering advice. Are you having trouble following the advice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947496/deprecated-commands-in-visual-c

Comment: [InetPton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to work around this:

- use `inet_pton()` or `InetPton()` instead, or
- define `_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS` to disable deprecated API warnings.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Working !! Thank you alot , for some reason the inet_pton didnt work but the second solution did work ! ty

Comment: @user4825345: And what about `InetPton`? You really should focus on getting the "correct" solution working (it works for everybody else!) rather than masking warnings.