# winsock deprecated no warnings

Tags: visual-c++, winsock

I am trying to create a UDP multicast socket program using VS2015 (C++ console application).

I got the following error,

```
Error   C4996   'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings mulitcast_listener
```

I tried to add _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS symbol to my project settings via "Project"->"Properties"->"Configuration properties"->"C/C++"->"Preprocessor"->"Preprocessor definitions"
.. But still it says the same.

And then I tried to add symbol above **#include "stdafx.h"**
like

*#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS   1*

and then **No(/sdl-)** on "Project"->"Properties"->"Configuration properties"->"C/C++"->General->SDL checks

now I get a error message saying

```
Warning C4603   '_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS': macro is not defined or definition is different after precompiled header
```

Finally I tried to implement

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, HELLO_GROUP, (PVOID *)(&mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr));
```

instead of

```
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(HELLO_GROUP);
```

I need to understand why the error didn't resolved even after adding the _WINSOCK... macro.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding adding the `#define` before `stdafx.h` you might not be aware of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header#stdafx.h . `#include "stdafx.h"` should be first thing. What happens if you place the `#define` right after including stdafx but before all other includes?

Comment: It build successfully.. Thank you so much for this information

Answer (score 19):

As noted in the comments, the solution is to make sure that the line

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
```

is placed after

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

but before the other `#include` statements.

Answer (score 5):

While the previous advice works, it is ignoring the purpose of `stdafx.h`. The idea is that you place `#include` statements for header files that don't change frequently *inside* `stdafx.h` in order to make use of precompiled headers. Therefore you should ideally place

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPCRECATED
```

inside `stdafx.h`, before other `#include` statements that it affects, in particular before including `winsock2.h` or other winsock related headers.

Answer (score 0):

```
// pch.h
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS    // defined here and it worked

#include "framework.h"
#include "xxx.h"
```